# Setting the pixel color of BufferedImage using byte array

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bytebuffer

I have converted an image to an array using the following code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;       
try {
   bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("name.jpeg"));
} catch (IOException e) { }

byte[] b = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

The array contains 3 bytes for each pixel. My question is how can I set individual pixel to white, because the problem is that byte in Java is signed, thus allowing only values between -128 and 127. But I want to set my pixel to 255, 255, 255. If I set all three values to 127 the pixel turns out grey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the values to `-1`, which is the [signed representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of the unsigned `255` byte.

Or if you want to make the code more obvious, `(byte)255` will also make it work.

Comment: Man how did not see that. I was trying with -1 but didn't notice it actually made it white. I feel stupid now... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Java's built in [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to help manage this kind of stuff.  Not sure if you need to specifically have a `byte[]` array but it's cool object you can leverage.

Comment: Yes I need byte array because I am trying to implement some low level filters and need to be able to manipulate each individual pixel.

Comment: `BufferedImage` doesn't work with `ByteBuffers` (or at least not when I last checked). The `DataBuffer` classes are a different breed altogether.

Comment: @Kayaman They do now fortunately :-)  You are able to loop over each byte individually and apply logic to it if you so desired but it seems like you've got a good answer in the -1 already :-)

Comment: I don't see any reference to `ByteBuffer` in JDK 8. It's `Raster` and `DataBuffer` all the way.

Comment: I believe it's the case that ByteBuffer was introduced in jdk 7. It compiles in jdk 8 though. I've tested code using the ByteBuffer and BufferedImage using jdk 1.8.102 I believe and I haven't had a problem. I can pm you the code so you can take a look if you'd like so we don't clutter the comments